# Python get previous day of week (Thursday in my example) from pandas date column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas date column and I want to return the date for the previous Thursday (could be any day of week). I use pd.offsets.Week but I do not get the expected result when the year changes and the Week starts over. Here is my dataframe as 'd':

`raw date   Thursday week_start
0  2019-01-03 2018-12-27 2018-12-27
1  2019-01-03 2018-12-27 2018-12-27
2  2019-01-03 2018-12-27 2018-12-27
3  2019-01-02 2018-12-27 2018-12-27
4  2019-01-02 2018-12-27 2018-12-27
5  2019-01-02 2018-12-27 2018-12-27
6  2019-01-03 2019-01-03 2018-12-27
7  2019-01-03 2019-01-03 2018-12-27
8  2019-01-03 2019-01-03 2018-12-27
9  2019-01-03 2019-01-03 2018-12-27
10 2019-01-02 2018-12-27 2018-12-27
11 2019-01-02 2018-12-27 2018-12-27
12 2019-01-02 2018-12-27 2018-12-27`

```
d['week_start'] = d['raw date'] - pd.offsets.Week(weekday=3)
```

I expected where d['week_start'] = 1/3/2019 to return 1/3/2019, not 12/27/2018. I suspect it is because the Week at 1/3/2019 is 0 so it returns the Thursday of that week. How can I get the previous Thursday's date regardless of a change in the year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) with [`Series.dt.weekday`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.weekday.html) for change only not `Thursday` values:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2019-01-03', periods=20)
d = pd.DataFrame({'raw date': rng}) 

mask = d['raw date'].dt.weekday == 3
d['week_start'] = d['raw date'].where(mask, d['raw date'] - pd.offsets.Week(weekday=3))
print(d)
     raw date week_start
0  2019-01-03 2019-01-03
1  2019-01-04 2019-01-03
2  2019-01-05 2019-01-03
3  2019-01-06 2019-01-03
4  2019-01-07 2019-01-03
5  2019-01-08 2019-01-03
6  2019-01-09 2019-01-03
7  2019-01-10 2019-01-10
8  2019-01-11 2019-01-10
9  2019-01-12 2019-01-10
10 2019-01-13 2019-01-10
11 2019-01-14 2019-01-10
12 2019-01-15 2019-01-10
13 2019-01-16 2019-01-10
14 2019-01-17 2019-01-17
15 2019-01-18 2019-01-17
16 2019-01-19 2019-01-17
17 2019-01-20 2019-01-17
18 2019-01-21 2019-01-17
19 2019-01-22 2019-01-17
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I was missing the conditional part for where dt.weekday == day of week I want. Thanks for the mask and .where, it now works in my intended code base.

Answer (score 0):

this can be done using pd.TimeDeltaIndex.

df["date"].dt.dayofweek-3+7) will give days before Thursday of next week

df["date"].dt.dayofweek-3+7)%7 will give days after last Thursday

```py
date_range = pd.date_range('2019-9-20', periods=20)
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': date_range}) 

df["week_start"] = df["date"] - pd.TimedeltaIndex((df["date"].dt.dayofweek-3+7)%7, "D")
df
```

**Result**

```
    date    date dayofweek  week_start  week_start dayofweek
0   2019-09-20  4   2019-09-19  3
1   2019-09-21  5   2019-09-19  3
2   2019-09-22  6   2019-09-19  3
3   2019-09-23  0   2019-09-19  3
4   2019-09-24  1   2019-09-19  3
5   2019-09-25  2   2019-09-19  3
6   2019-09-26  3   2019-09-26  3
7   2019-09-27  4   2019-09-26  3
8   2019-09-28  5   2019-09-26  3
9   2019-09-29  6   2019-09-26  3
10  2019-09-30  0   2019-09-26  3
11  2019-10-01  1   2019-09-26  3
12  2019-10-02  2   2019-09-26  3
13  2019-10-03  3   2019-10-03  3
14  2019-10-04  4   2019-10-03  3
15  2019-10-05  5   2019-10-03  3
16  2019-10-06  6   2019-10-03  3
17  2019-10-07  0   2019-10-03  3
18  2019-10-08  1   2019-10-03  3
19  2019-10-09  2   2019-10-03  3
```